# Unit testing Put method within Microsoft EF Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

I am following an article - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2 - to unit test Web API 2 controller.

There, the author tests put method like below:

```
   //....

   Product GetDemoProduct()
    {
        return new Product() { Id = 3, Name = "Demo name", Price = 5 };
    }

   [TestMethod]
    public void PutProduct_ShouldReturnStatusCode()
    {
        var controller = new ProductController(new TestStoreAppContext());

        //** Edited myself from original:
        //** var item = GetDemoProduct(); 
        var updatedItem = new Product(){ Id = 3, Name = "Demo name", Price = 6 };

        var result = controller.PutProduct(3, updatedItem) as StatusCodeResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(StatusCodeResult));
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, result.StatusCode);
        //** Added a new assertion.
        Assert.AreEqual(updatedItem.Price, GetDemoProduct().Price);
    }
```

Which tests put method within controller

```
public IHttpActionResult PutProduct(int id, Product product)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != product.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    //db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.MarkAsModified(product);

     try
     {
        db.SaveChanges();
     }

     //....
     return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);     
}
```

To verify that update actually happens, I added few lines to the original test method which are indicated by ** in the block.

Well, the mock data item doesn't get updated in the end. Price remains the same as the pre-update product price.

How come db.SaveChanges(); doesn't work?

Comment: `var updatedItem = new item(){ Id =` you have a class somewhere called `item`?

Comment: Sorry, That was copy-paste typo. It should be Product instance.

Comment: So without asserting updatedItem == pre-updatedItem, example unit test is doing fine. It returns NoCoentent status codel. Just that it's doesn't actually update mock database.

Answer (score 0):

Just Found out that Author intentionally changed saveChanges method within test context.

```
public class TestStoreAppContext : IStoreAppContext 
{
    public TestStoreAppContext()
    {
        this.Products = new TestProductDbSet();
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //....
```

Now need to think why he changed the saveChanges() method.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

1) You initiallize updatedItem with a Price of 6 (your reference mock has price of 5), pass it to the PutProduct method, but the method never modifies the price.  I am not sure what you were expecting to happen.  If you don't modify the price, obviously it will be the same. Did you intend to do `product.Price = 5` somewhere?  Otherwise it will not match your reference object and will still have a Price of 6.

2) Using an assert in the input parameter of a WebAPI method is a bad test.  `updatedItem` is going to in practice come from an HTTP request that is bound to the parameter.  Whether you modify the properties of that entity makes little difference to anything outside of the method because nothing else has a reference to it.  You have a reference to it in the test case only because that's how we are faking the HTTP request.  We skipped the whole model binding step.  In reality no one would ever have a reference to it and it would be completely irrelevant after the call completes.  You should only be concerned with two things, the state of the database and the return.  You've got the return testing down, you just are offbase with testing the database modification.  First to emphasize why this test is bad:

Consider if I forgot to call SaveChanges:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutProduct(int id, Product product)
{
     product.Price = 5;
     return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);     
}
```

Your assertion would succeed because my modification would cause updatedProduct to have a price of 5 and thus match the reference object:

`Assert.AreEqual(updatedItem.Price, GetDemoProduct().Price);`

However the implementation of PutProduct is wrong as the programmer forgot to call SaveChanges, but your test case missed this.  You would really need to query the database through the same context to see if the changes were actually persisted.  You could do this with an actual localdb, which works well if you configure EF to clear DB with each test run, or the more "proper" approach is to use a context that maps to an inmemory mock.  This is the approach used here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/unit-testing-in-mvc-4-using-entity-framework/

If we assumed you had such a repository it'd be something like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void Create_PutProductInRepository()
 {      
     int testId = 3;     
     ...
     var result = controller.PutProduct(testId, inputProduct) as StatusCodeResult;
     ...
     // This is the kind of testing you really want to be doing.
     //  You want to "assert that the item exists in the database and has the expected value"
     Product productAfterTest = mockrepository.GetProduct(testId);
     Assert.AreEqual(inputProduct.Price, productAfterTest.Price);
 }
```

Obivously you are using an approach which does not have a repository, so you'll have to adapt this.  Point being, the assertion needs to performa  query to retrieve the item from your dbcontext to verify it exists and expected modifications were saved.  I'm no expert on making in memory databases, so whatever source you have for your approach you'll have to gain an understanding of.  But either way you should be doing your assertions by going to database context and retrieving the item to verify it REALLY was persisted to the context.

Comment: Thank you. Well I think I need to look into these.